# Javascript to open popup window and disable parent window

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to open a popup window and disable the parent window. Below is the code that I am using;

```
function popup()
{

    popupWindow = window.open('child_page.html','name','width=200,height=200');
    popupWindow.focus();
}
```

For some reason, the parent window does not get disabled. Do I need some additional code OR what is the case?

Again, I am looking for something similar to what we get when we use showModalDialog()..i.e. it does not allow to select parent window at all..Only thing is I want to get the same thing done using window.open

Also please suggest the code which will be cross-browser compatible..

Comment: what do you mean by "disable the parent window"?

Comment: Disable would mean not allow the user to select say text on the parent window..in fact not allow him to select anything on the parent..

Comment: **You may refer to the below link as well.** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376102/how-to-disable-parent-window-while-child-window-appear-by-clicking-button-on-par

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var popupWindow=null;

function popup()
{
    popupWindow = window.open('child_page.html','name','width=200,height=200');
}

function parent_disable() {
if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
popupWindow.focus();
}
```

and then declare these functions in the body tag of parent window

```
<body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
```

As you requested here is the complete html code of the parent window

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popupWindow=null;

function child_open()
{ 

popupWindow =window.open('new.jsp',"_blank","directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");

}
function parent_disable() {
if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
popupWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
    <a href="javascript:child_open()">Click me</a>
</body>    
</html>
```

Content of new.jsp below

```
<html>
<body>
I am child
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this in IE..But it allows me to select or play with the parent window.

Comment: what do you mean by you can select parent window, because for me it is working fine.It will not allow you to perform any action on the parent window

Comment: For me, I can perform action on the parent while the child is open..Could you copy/paste the complte HTML code which you have..

Comment: I have edited my answer with the full html code for both the windows.

Comment: I copy pasted the code you gave as it is..Still when I open the popup, I can select text in the parent..I tested it in IE8...
Not sure if there is any communication gap, but what I am looking for exactly is something similar to what we get when we use showModalDialog()..i.e. it does not allow to select parent window at all..Only thing is I want to get the same thing using window.open...

Comment: Yes you will be able to select text but as i mentioned earlier you cannot perform any action like clicking a link or button etc.The exact masking as you get with modal window is not possible i guess

Comment: Can you please post the complete html/javascript code for this..very much needed for me. Thanks !!

Comment: @Rahul Almost all of the code is already present in the post. Can you specify which part you did not understand or are having issue with?

Comment: You can add some few more lines in your code to block the parent .<script type="text/javascript">
function disableParent() {
 if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
  popupWindow.focus();

 document.onmousedown = focusPopup; 
 document.onkeyup = focusPopup; 
 document.onmousemove = focusPopup;
 document.onclick = focusPopup; 
}
function focusPopup() {
  if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed) { popupWindow.focus(); } 
} 
</script>

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, you cannot disable the browser window.

What you can do is create a [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (or a similar kind of ) popup and when this popup appears your parent browser will be disabled.

Open your child page in popup.

Comment: I know the jQuery modal dialog..But i cannot use that..it is actually a div within the same page..

Comment: @hmthur - if you dont want it to be in same page then you can use `iframe` within that div and give the page you want to see in the `src` attribute of `iframe`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I finally did it! You can put a layer (full sized) over your body with high z-index and, of course hidden. You will make it visible when the window is open, make it focused on click over parent window (the layer), and finally will disappear it when the opened window is closed or submitted or whatever.

```
      .layer
  {
        position: fixed;
        opacity: 0.7;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 999999;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        display: none;
        cursor: not-allowed;
  }
```

and layer in the body:

```
                <div class="layout" id="layout"></div>
```

function that opens the popup window:

```
    var new_window;
    function winOpen(){
        $(".layer").show();
        new_window=window.open(srcurl,'','height=750,width=700,left=300,top=200');
    }
```

keeping new window focused:

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".layout").click(function(e) {
                new_window.focus();
            }
        });
```

and in the opened window:

```
    function submit(){
        var doc = window.opener.document,
        doc.getElementById("layer").style.display="none";
         window.close();
    }   

   window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        var doc = window.opener.document;
        doc.getElementById("layout").style.display="none";
   }
```

I hope it would help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key term is modal-dialog.

As such there is no built in modal-dialog offered.

But you can use many others available e.g. [this](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi the answer that @anu posted is right, but it wont completely work as required. By making a slight change to **child_open() function** it works properly.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popupWindow=null;

function child_open()
{ 
if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
   popupWindow.focus();
else
   popupWindow =window.open('new.jsp',"_blank","directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");

}
function parent_disable() {
  if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
    popupWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
  <body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
     <a href="javascript:child_open()">Click me</a>
  </body>    
</html>
```