# How to disable parent window while child window appear by clicking button on parent window

Tags: javascript

I have designed one window in jsp in  which there is a search button. when user clicks "search" button, the new window appears. But at this time i want my parent window to be disable so that when user tried to do anything on parent window it should not allow until "search" form is closed.

If anyone knows how to do this then please let me know.

i have already tried this solution [Javascript to open popup window and disable parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window),     but this solution is not able to disable the links on the parent page. 
and I don't intend to use showmodaldialog.
Or somebody can explain me the use of showdialog() with an example
Thanks,
rakesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function openSearchPopUp() { 
  popupWindow= window.open(url,'window','width=800,
                           height=600,location=yes,
                           menubar=‌​yes,scrollbars=yes,
                           resizable=yes'); 
  popupWindow.focus(); 
  document.onmousedown = focusPopup; 
  document.onkeyup = focusPopup; 
  document.onmousemove = focusPopup; 
} 

function focusPopup() {
  if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed) { popupWindow.focus(); } 
}
```

Comment: It is working in IE 8.0, but it is not working in Google Chrome .

Answer (score 2):

The way I present modal windows is I create a DIV that covers the entire document, with a high Z-index, and then I prevent propagation of click events. In jQuery, I'd do it like this:

```
// When popup window is open:
var $cover = $('<div>');
$cover.css({
  height: $(document).height(),
  width: $(document).width(),
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  background: 'black',
  opacity: 0.5
});
$cover.click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   return false;
});
$cover.appendTo(document);
```

**EDIT:** Here's something I did quick-and-dirty using pure JS. I'm sure it can be improved for better cross-browser support.

http://jsfiddle.net/wVNbx/1/

Comment: i have used this kind of approach using this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Modal-PopUp-using-JavaScript.aspx , but it is able to color only vertical half of parent window

Comment: I've actually implemented the above approach on a site I'm developing, and it works. Check out the result at https://herdhound.com/ (click the "get started" button in the top-right corner.

Comment: @rcky: Not too familiar with pure client-side JS, but if I come up with something, I'll let you know.

Comment: I don't know how JSP works, but you should add a script tag into parent window, copy the modalCover object into it, and call the modalCover.create() method just before the child window is spawned.

Comment: @foxbunny......thanks for ur help....used some other appraoch and its working fine....

Comment: You should update the question and/or add your solution to the answers so that someone can use it if they have the same problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Greybox** . Please visit the link : http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/

Hope this will suffice your requirement.