# Pop up window not working properly

Tags: javascript

The onclick function is not working properly as it is disabling all the links on the parent window even after I close it.
On closing the pop up window, the parent page links are not working anymore. Everything else is working fine.

My code is:-

```
             function MyPopUpWin(message) {
             var iMyWidth;
         var iMyHeight;
         //half the screen width minus half the new window width (plus 5 pixel borders).
           iMyWidth = (window.screen.width/2) - (75 + 10);
         //half the screen height minus half the new window height (plus title and status bars).
          iMyHeight = (window.screen.height/2) - (100 + 50);
         //Open the window.
 var generator = window.open();
document.onclick=function()   {
    try{
        generator.focus();
        return false
    }
    catch(e){}
}

generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Pop uP</title>');
generator.document.write('<p style="color:#C52B27;">');
generator.document.write(message);
generator.document.write('</p>');
generator.document.write('</head><body>');

 generator.document.write('<a href="javascript:self.close()"><img src="/img/save_orange.gif" border=0">  <\/a>');
generator.document.write('</body></html>');
generator.document.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closing the window, the reference to it is not lost... and the `.focus()` method does not fail.. so you `try`/`catch` is not doing what you think..

```
<a href="javascript:window.opener.document.onclick = null;self.close();">
```

Comment: .....thanks man , it is working fine....but can dere be some other solution .last time i did a pop up problem and proposed  this soltion to my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376102/how-to-disable-parent-window-while-child-window-appear-by-clicking-button-on-par .....but this time this focus code not working in my function

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `onclick`-eventhandler from `document` after the pop-up is closed.

**Edited:**

I dont know which could be even better than Gaby's answer, but try this:

```
document.body.onfocus=function (){generator.focus();return false;}
```

and then nullify `onfocus` when exiting your pop-up.

Or just use a (partly?) transparent cover `div` over the parent window, while pop-up is open.

**2nd edition**

Or even use `showModaDialog()` for your pop-up, though this solution needs an other file to load to modal dialog.

Comment: @rcky Do you mean, that links should be active in the parent document, while the pop-up is open?

Comment: no.....i want that when pop up opens the parent page links should get disabled and on closing it , links should be active , but by some better approach

Comment: @Teemu..last time i used this soltion and trying to use the same code this time but its not working now .the link to the solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376102/how-to-disable-parent-window-while-child-window-appear-by-clicking-button-on-par

Comment: @Teemu...this soltion is working fine till few clicks but after that pop up is no more on top

Comment: Maybe some sandbox issue, actually I didn't test it. I would use modal dialog instead of opening a window.

Comment: @Teemu........can not use showModaDialog() as i am not specifying the url of the page it is opening

Comment: I can't understand. Just save the file in your server, and load it to your modal pop-up, pass the `message` through dialog's parameters, that's all.