# How to open a popup with lock the remain screen in HTML?

Tags: html

i am trying to open a popup in my screen where i can lock the remain screen so that the user can only select something from my popup or can cancel the popup.
Basically i need to pass some value from a jsp form to my popup, that i had done but i also need to lock the remaining screen that i am not able to do so far. 
Thanks.

This is how i am calling the jQuery

```
 <a href="#" class="modalInput"  rel="#prompt">Download</a>
```

This is my Script

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
    mask: {
        color: '#555555',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
},
closeOnClick: false
});

var buttons = $("#yesno button").click(function(e) {
    var yes = buttons.index(this) === 0;
    triggers.eq(0).html("You clicked " + (yes ? "yes" : "no"));
});

$("#prompt form").submit(function(e) {
        triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();
        var input = $("input", this).val();
        triggers.eq(1).html(input);
        return e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my Form

```
<font  face=arial  bgcolor=""><b><center>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="SentMail" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">   
<div class="modal" id="prompt" > 
<div id="">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle"><span style="color:#F00">*</span> Mandotary Field</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Name:</strong><span style="color:#F00">*</span></td>
                        <td width="72%" align="left" valign="middle"><label for="textfield"></label>
                          <div class="out-border">
                          <input name="name" type="text" class="comm-text" id="name" style="width:250px" placeholder="Name"/></div></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Email:</strong><span style="color:#F00">*</span></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="textfield2"></label>
                          <div class="out-border">
                          <input name="Email" type="text" class="comm-text" id="Email" style="width:250px" placeholder="Email"/></div></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Contact No.:</strong></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle"><label for="textfield2"></label>
                          <div class="out-border">
                          <input name="contact" type="text" class="comm-text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="10" id="contact" style="width:250px" placeholder="Contact Number"/></div></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="signIn" value="Submit" class="button green"> </input>
                      <input type="button" name="signIn" value="Close" class="close"> </input></td>
                      </tr>

                    </table>
                  </div></div>
    </form>
</center></b></font>
```

Comment: Bad idea, a user would hate this and probably leave your site

Comment: what you are looking for is a modal popup

Comment: Are you using **jQuery UI**? If so you can use a **modal dialog** (if you're using something else...just pick a rando modal dialog implementation).

Comment: i need to do somthing like this http://www.etcproceedings.org/paper/a130-a-design-build-finance-and-operate-project    here when u click on "Download paper" then u will be ask for enter your email id and name. i need to do somthing like this

Comment: @Adriano yes i am using JQuery but i am not able to send my value through it

Comment: Why not? Anyway you may use it to display the modal popup, keeping the communication logic untouched.

Comment: There is a same answered here, you can look into this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window

Comment: @RabNawazKhan Thanks for your reply but it is not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com) - especially [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and the [modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal) option.

Comment: i am using jQuery but it is not allowing to send value from my jsp page to that dialog.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong in the markup. JSP is a server language and shouldn't have any impact on your JavaScript markup, as that is run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using "window.open". Use window.showModalDialog