# Pop up Jsp page which looks like a JS pop up?

Tags: jsp, popup

I'm working with JSP and if button clicked on the page will display a pop up(not new window) and need to do some work before processing it.
 so using javascript the functionality is not able to be acheivable.
 So i want to pop up(not new window) a JSP page and it should look like JS pop only.
 Bcoz the end user should not get the feeling that it is a separate window..
Any idea is highly Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the functionality you are looking for is known as fancy box [Click here to see it in action](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: Hi pKs, It will just pop up.. But i want the popup of jsp like JS popup. And in the pop up i want to have two buttons, until i press either of buttons, The parent window should be focusless. Child only should have focus...

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window ... hope this helps you

Comment: I need a popup not a new window pKs.. So it is not useful as per the context of the question raised.. I need popup a jsp not the new window.. I hope you understood..

Comment: I guess I got you ... You want a fancy box and in that a jsp will do.. check it here.. http://fancybox.net/ and click any of the image..

Comment: Thanks so much PKs.. I need this kind of solution only... Thank you for your valuable time spent for me..

Comment: You should use the power of up vote to help others looking for certain answers.. I am editing the answer though..

Comment: Use power of up vote it may help the others who are looking for the same answer .

Comment: I agree for it.. I haven't upvoted bcoz earlier that was not the correct one i expected. After you edited i will do..

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, I have to use Jquery Dialog concept.. so that the dialog box content will be a jsp code only. In this way the requirement was fulfilled.