# Show Popup Form Login in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, fba

My sharepoint site is `Form Authentication Based` and configurated properly. When i login, it redirects to page `/_layouts/login.aspx`

**What i want is:** when i click Login label, i want to show popup to login to site as when using windows authentication.

Comment: You can do something like given in the answers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like given in the answers

[Javascript to open popup window and disable parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window)

In this there is a javascript which shows a code to open a windows as a popup. You can call this javascript with the name of your application login page.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's a simple popup. but i mean: When i click Login label or access any page which required login, web app will redirect to "/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx" and redirect login page. I want when it go to Authenticate.aspx, it open a popup login, not as defautl login page available. Thanks.