# How to pop a dialog box /iframe/Lightbox like one below above the webpage content

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to pop a dialog box like one below /iframe above the webpage content disabling the web page content using html/css/javascript.
eg:when you click login in IMDB
pls do help
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

You should configure it as a modal, so the main page is disabled. You also can give the style you want or create your own with [Theme roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
```

If it helps, I've created a jsfiddle with the example in the official doc. 
http://jsfiddle.net/K3YWR/

Answer (score 0):

I think Following Link will be used to answer your question. This Stackoverflow have discussion about popup a dialog box with disabling the parent web page content.

Link:

[popup a dialog box with disabling the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window)

Comment: See Also This Link :
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/