# How to disable the browser parent window when child window open?

Tags: javascript, windows

I have a scenario like when i open the child widow by clicking the button in the parent window, here i want to disable the entire parent window.
I have seen many examples in the stackoverflow and google but i had not any luck and i used the following code and it does not work for me

```
<script>
var childWin = window.open(url, "_blank", "enabled");
childWin.focus();
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window

Comment: I have seen that code, but it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var popupWindow = null;

        function child_open() {
            popupWindow = window.open('URL', "_blank", "directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");

        }
        function parent_disable() {
            if (popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
                popupWindow.focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="width: 670px; height: 670px" onfocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
    <a href="javascript:child_open()">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: I worked with that code, but it is not complete thing i wanted, it is allowing the user to work on parent window

Comment: @M.S.Naidu... did you get any answer for this? please post entire code if yes...thanks!!