# Disabling window while opening popup

Tags: javascript

I've looked around this site a bit, and can't seem to find a solution that works for me...
I'm trying to disable parent window while opening a popup- I've tried:
`<body onClick="func1()" onFocus="func1()">`
with
`editwindow = window.open("","","width=300, height=300");`
with the following function in my header:
`function func1()`
`{`
`if (editwindow && !editwindow.closed) editwindow.focus();`

`}`

My problem is that this method doesn't effectively "disable" the parent window. I need links and buttons not to respond when clicked on. It seems like the browser is giving preference to the links first, and then re-focuses to the popup window.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the future it would be smart to included more code you've already written and tried (working or not), along with your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to open popup window and disable parent window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window)

Comment: Actually, I tried what was recommended there. It didn't seem to disable links in the opener window.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, and dealing with pop-up blocker headaches in the future ruining your User Experience, you might consider using [jQuery UI's modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```