# Returning focus to the parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pages called as "Form_1.html" and "Form_2.html".

- "Form_1.html" is the parent window from which i am opening "Form_2.html" using window.open() method.
- Now what i want is that when i write window.close() in the child window("Form_2.html") i want the focus to return back to "Form_1.html" and the parent window should get refreshed.
- I want it in javascript only because i cannot use jquery(because it is not allowed).

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have written this after my work in child window is done.

window.close();   window.open("Form_1.html","_self");

but how to refresh the parent page now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
function RefreshParent() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;
```

You can find a demo here : http://aspsnippets.com/demos/542/

Comment: can you answer me one more thing similiar to this?

it is regarding focus only?

Comment: This will refresh the parent window from where you open a child popup.

Comment: how can i disable my parent window when my child window is opened and then enable it back again when the child window is closed?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window