# i am opening new window popup using javascript which will restrict user from using its parent window

Tags: javascript, dom, window.open

I am opening new window pop up using `window.open` method which will restrict user to use its parent window till the new window is not closed. User will not be able switch back to parent window till child window is open.

How can I do it using JavaScript? please guide me..

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Use a modal dialog in the same window to get that effect.

Comment: **Thankfully** you can't do this just with Javascript - you *might* get away with a somehow hacky server-side solution though - if at all possible

Comment: but how im new to dis ??

Comment: that would be a big security risk if browsers implemented that. could you just have the main window go to the other page?

Comment: okay actually im developing python django app which is integrated with linkedin oauth ....so have server side so u can help me out with server side also

Comment: no we can't unless you show code illustrating you attempts at nearly succeeding:p

Answer (score -1):

To disable the parent window until child window closed you might want to use `window.showModalDialog()` instead of `window.open()`.

To use showmodalDialog [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog)

note: However, that you can not use `window.opener` from a modal dialog box (it will always be null) unless you explicitly pass a reference to the parent window in the second argument to `showModalDialog()` and get it back using `window.dialogArguments`.

Comment: err there is big note on the top of the link warning NOT to use this - And anyway I've tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: hope this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window