# Downloading file clicking on Linkbutton asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to provide a linkbutton(asp) with a click function attached to it in c#. When the user clicks on the linkbutton the backend code sends a pdf file to the user for download.

I have completed the code and it seems to download the file when the page is opened. But in one of my cases it opens the page as a windows dialog.

In this case, When I click on the linkbutton the code executes but there is no download operations that happens. The download of the document fails when the same page is loaded inside the Window dialog that is opened using windows.open.

Eg: Parent Page: Dashboard.aspx
    Child Page: DownloadFormatSelector.aspx
I navigate to localhost/DownloadFormatSelector.aspx page and click on "Download" button the browser (IE) shows options to "Save As","Open".

But if I open the DownloadFormatSelector.aspx page from dashboard using window.showModalDialog. The download does not happen
Eg: localhost/Dashboard.aspx and DownloadFormatSelector.aspx page opens inside ot using window.showModalDialog.

I am stuck why when the page is rendered inside a window.showModalDialog it does not download the document or display the Save as option.

All the following codes are present in DownloadFormatSelector file.

Dashboard.aspx is just the parent window. I am able to perform download when the child window is navigated to (Like localhost/DownloadFormatSelector.aspx) but the same page when opened inside a window.showModalDialog I am not able to download the file has the page does not display any save as or open options below. what can I modify to perform save on the page inside the showmodaldialog

Code c# click:

```
public void DownloadButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] data=GetData();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
    String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "temp.pdf"));            
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    Response.End();
}
```

Asp.Net

```
<asp:LinkButton id="Link" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadButton_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Open as window dialog :

```
window.showModalDialog JS method to call another aspx page to be rendered inside the dialog window
```

Comment: What do you mean by "opens the page as a windows dialog"?  This code should send a file to the client, it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Hi David,

I am opening the aspx page similar to this article  window.open('child_page.html','name','width=200,height=200');.. From this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660700/javascript-to-open-popup-window-and-disable-parent-window

Comment: " page is loaded inside the Window dialog". What windows dialog? Do you mean you're getting a message asking if you want to open or save it?

Comment: either you're opening the page via the DownloadButton_Click event, or you're opening it with Javascript. It can't be both. The code to download anything is only inside the DownloadButton_Click event. If you load the page some other way e.g. using `window.open` this event will not get triggered, because no button was clicked.

Comment: @PradeepK: Instead of linking to things which might be similar to your code, demonstrate what you're doing in *your* code.  Edit the question to add relevant information.  Specify exactly what's failing.  For example, in your browser's debugging tools, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: Adyson ., I have the click event written on the aspx page that is loaded inside the window.open. 

Parent Page: Dashboard.aspx page
Child Page: DownloadFormatSelector.aspx page

The child page has the click event in it and the link button in it

Comment: does "child_page.html" even exist in your application, as per your sample code? If it does it certainly won't execute any ASP code. Is this your real code or just an example from elsewhere? Examples from elsewhere do not help us to fix _your_ code. However, showing _your_ code might be useful. If this _is_ your code, it should surely be obvious that this is not the name of a page that you need to call??

Comment: @PradeepK: How is that line of JavaScript associated with that link button?  How are you preventing post back?  How is that HTML page executing your server-side code?  It's not clear from the code in your question what you're actually doing.

Comment: I guys., Thanks for the input ., I have modified the question and hope it helps. 

@Adyson: what I showed in the link was an example but not the same I am doing. there the name is replaced by my aspx page.

Comment: well please show your version instead, otherwise it's misleading. Anyway I'm confused. You open the page using window.open. So it opens in a new tab/window, am I right? So then what? You still have to press the button before anything will download, because the download happens only when the button is pressed, because the download code is inside the event handler for that button. I said that in my first comment. Did you not understand?

Comment: It's hard to see why you think opening the page in a new window would make any difference to the process.

Comment: @PradeepK: No, the modified question does not help at all.  The problem you're describing still makes no sense.  There's nothing connecting that link button to that JavaScript, and there's nothing connecting that JavaScript to that server-side button click handler.  You're trying to open something called `child_page.html`, which has nothing to do with ASP.NET server-side code.  It seems like you've just pasted random bits of code and are trying to get someone to write a complete solution for you, which isn't going to happen here.

Comment: David I have given the example as the real code does this value assign dynamically when it loads. To avoid confusion I have given the example to try focusing my issue. I dont expect someone to write the code for me. I think I referred articles on other stack overflow thread and have done it. When I download code does not work when it opens in showmodeldialog. That i my issue and I am trying to see how to work around it

Comment: you _still_ haven't shown your _actual_ JS code to open the new window. `window.showModalDialog JS method to call another aspx page to be rendered inside the dialog window` is not code. But if that function's what you're using, it's not a big surprise it doesn't work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog - it's been removed in most modern browsers. You've possibly got an error in your browser console if you're using a newish Chrome or Firefox. If it still does work, it won't in future.

Comment: And even if it's opening the window, you still haven't grasped that as well as opening the page you have to press the download button before a download can happen. You seem to be expecting it to download automatically. It's not clear why you expect this. Both David and I have explained this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Response.TransmitFile`. Here's how you do it:

```
public void DownloadButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = "path to your file";
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=whatever.ext");
    Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Hi Bozhidar, Thanks for the code. But I the problem is related to the JS window.showModalDialog which is not letting the child window display the save as or Open option